# The word "but" used as negation

Tags: negation

I would like to know the grammatical term for using the word *but* in the following context:

> John speaks loudly, but he's a nice guy.

The word *but* is used to signify a negation, to create contrast. Is there a term to describe this specific negation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As ruakh and Barrie have pointed out, *but* is a coordinating conjunction. Logically, it means the same as *and*, unlike the other coordinating conjunction, *or*, which is quite different.
The difference between *and* and *but* is not logical or even semantic, but rather pragmatic.

If *A* is true and *B* is true, **both** conjoined constructions in the set {*A and B*, *A but B*} indicate this fact. However, *A but B* carries in addition a presumption to the effect that the speaker did not expect *B* given *A*, or believed that *A*'s being true would normally contradict *B*, or was for some other reason surprised that *B* is true in this context.

There is no special technical term to denote this except, possibly, *contrastive*. It is **not**, however, *negation,* of any sort.

Comment: Thanks all for replying. I consulted Wikipedia and according to the article on Conjunction, my example is also known under the name "correlative conjunctions". Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)

Comment: Actually, correlative conjunctions come in pairs, like _not only ... but also,_ or _neither ... nor._

Comment: +1 For both answer and comment. I think the line about 'not a negation' should have been the first sentence.

Answer (score 6):

It's sometimes called a [*contrastive conjunction*](https://www.google.com/search?q=contrastive-conjunction).

Answer (score 2):

As in many similar contexts, it's a conjunction. More specifically, it's a coordinating conjunction, or a coordinator.

Comment: No, it's a *coordinating* conjunction, coordinating the independent clauses "John speaks loudly" and "he's a nice guy". (Note that you can't say \*"But John's a nice guy, he speaks loudly"; if *but* were a subordinating connection introducing a subordinate clause, you would be able to move that clause to the beginning of the independent clause.)

Comment: @ruakh: Yes, my carelessness. Now edited.